# Python & BeautifulSoup : Issues with soup.find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
h1 = soup.find('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'})['title']
print (h1)
```

I had no problem to take the value which is in title tag with the soup.find function.
But there is multiple tag like that on the page I am parsing, so I've to use the soup.find_all function, and it's not working.

With this code

```
    h1 = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'})['title']
    print (h1)
```

I had this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 8, in <module>
    h1 = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'})['title']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `find_all` returns a list, do you need all tag titles ?

Comment: Yes, I need all the tag titles !

Answer (score 2):

this should work :

```
results = [a['title'] for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep in mind that `find_all` function returns a list of `soup` objects by which you have filtered, in your case by a `class`.

What you are next trying to do is:

`h1 = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'})['title']`
`soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'})` is a list and you are trying to access `['title']` which is wrong.

so the best way to receive `title` from:

```
titles = map(lambda soup_object: soup_object['title'], soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'lien-jv topic-title'}))
```